# Custom cursor's position moves when scrolling upward

Tags: html, css, gsap

I'm making a custom hover cursor on my video div but it's not moving with my mouse stays at its position when I scroll, Can you all take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong. And one more thing that when I remove the loading animation from my video tag it goes back to normal but if my mouse cursor is inside the (#play) it will stick to my mouse and wont disappear until I move my mouse outside of it even thought I have put the mouse enter, leave and move on my (#video-container) and sorry for my poor English,
Thanks.

```js
function loadingAnim() {
  gsap.from("#page1 h1", {
    y: 100,
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 0.5,
    duration: 0.9,
    stagger: 0.2,
  });

  gsap.from("#page1 #video-container", {
    y: 100,
    opacity: 0,
    delay: 1.5,
    duration: 0.9,
  });
}

loadingAnim();

function videoCursor() {
  var videocon = document.querySelector("#video-container");
  var playbtn = document.querySelector("#play");

  videocon.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    //   playbtn.style.opacity = 1;
    //   playbtn.style.scale = 1;
    gsap.to(playbtn, {
      scale: 1,
      opacity: 1,
    });
  });

  videocon.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    gsap.to(playbtn, {
      scale: 0,
      opacity: 0,
    });
  });

  videocon.addEventListener("mousemove", (dets) => {
    gsap.to(playbtn, {
      left: dets.clientX - 60,
      top: dets.clientY - 60,
    });
  });
}

videoCursor();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Gilroy-Medium", sans-serif;
}

*::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#page1 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 1.5vw;
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

#page1 h1 {
  font-size: 15.9vw;
  font-family: futura;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 14vw;
  letter-spacing: -0.5vw;
}

#video-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 95vw;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-top: 2vw;

  position: relative;
}

#video-container video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#video-container #play {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 3vw 2vw;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: futura;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  scale: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="page1">
            <h1>Change</h1>
            <h1>the course</h1>
            <div id="video-container">
                <div id="play">
                    PLAY
                </div>
                <video autoplay muted loop src="./video.mp4"></video>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.12.2/gsap.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-16esztaSRplJROstbIIdwX3N97V1+pZvV33ABoG1H2OyTttBxEGkTsoIVsiP1iaTtM8b3+hu2kB6pQ4Clr5yug=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Scrolling does not trigger mousemove events. You additionally have to subscribe scroll events. Since you set the height for your body to 100% you have to subscribe  the scroll event on the body element instead of the window. Unfortunately this still won't solve your problem, because the scroll event has no cursor position. You will need to calculate the scroll delta and work with that instead.

Comment: @AndréRaider I don't want to trigger mouse move on scrolling, I  just want my play cursor to follow my mouse when I enter the video div

Comment: Currently you just update the position of your play cursor in the callback function on mousemove. But scrolling does not trigger mousemove so the cursor does not get updated. I have proposed you a general approach how you can solve this problem.

Comment: @AndréRaider I fixed it by taking my cursor div outside of the wrapper in which smooth scrolling was applied

Comment: Great that you solved it. Can you paste your own solution here as an answer and mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!, By moving the cursor div outside of the wrapper ("#main") on which smooth scrolling is applied. Because position fixed don't work perfectly inside the wrapper on which smooth scrolling is applied.